# Laravel Eloquent Model query with custom select/join/order

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have models called Post, and PostView.  A Post can have many PostViews.
I need to get a paginated list of Posts ordered by the count of PostViews created within the last 30 days.

I can do this using `withCount`:

```
// works but S L O W
$posts = Post::withCount(['views' => function($query) {
            $query->where('post_views.created_at', '>=', 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)');
         }])
         ->orderBy('views_count')
         ->paginate(10);
```

However this generates a query that is *really* slow, taking ~24 seconds.

Using raw sql I can get the correct results much more efficiently, how can I turn that into the paginated model collection?

This generates the correct query to grab the first 10, but the resulting collection is empty. I assume it has something to do with the `selectRaw`

```
$posts = Post::selectRaw('posts.*, count(post_views.id) as views_count')
           ->join('post_views', function($join) {
                $join->on('posts.id', '=', 'post_views.post_id')
                   ->where('post_views.created_at', '>=', 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)');
            })
            ->groupBy('posts.id')
            ->orderBy('views_count', 'DESC')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();
```

If I run the query that generates directly in mysql I do get results: (note - truncated to posts.id for brevity)

```
mysql> select posts.id, count(post_views.id) as views_count from `posts` inner join `post_views` on `posts`.`id` = `post_views`.`post_id` and `post_views`.`created_at` >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) group by `posts`.`id` order by `views_count` desc limit 10;
+--------+-------------+
| id     | views_count |
+--------+-------------+
| 150277 |          22 |
|  43843 |           6 |
| 138789 |           4 |
| 180565 |           4 |
|  50555 |           3 |
|   2679 |           3 |
| 188572 |           3 |
| 217454 |           3 |
| 136736 |           3 |
| 126472 |           2 |
+--------+-------------+
10 rows in set (1.26 sec)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: instead of `get()` use `paginate()`.

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem that the collection is empty.  I used get() just to have it generate a single query.  I can worry about pagination once I can actually get the models.

Answer (score 0):

**The query should be :**

```
$posts = Post::selectRaw('posts.*, count(post_views.id) as views_count')
           ->join('post_views', function($join) {
                $join->on('posts.id', '=', 'post_views.post_id')
                   ->where('post_views.created_at', '>=', 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)');
            })
            ->groupBy('posts.id')
            ->orderBy('views_count', 'DESC')
            // ->take(10) // no need of this
            //->get(); // will be using paginate
             ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: I understand the `->paginate(10)` method on there, I was attempting to simplify it to show it as a single stand-alone query.
Even with paginate, my collection is empty:


```Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator Object
(
    [total:protected] => 0
    [lastPage:protected] => 0
    [items:protected] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
        (
            [items:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )
    // truncated
)```

Any idea why it's empty if the raw query has results?

Comment: In my case its working.. can you provide me with your data so i'll test on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
PostViews::where('created_at', '>=', 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)')->groupBy('post_id')->selectRaw('count(*) as post_count')->with('post')->paginate(10);
```

Assumming you have an index on `created_at`

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out - the join->where clause was getting escaped and invalidating the query.  Not invalid sql, just an invalid comparison such that there would always be no results.

Of course the query logger didn't show that it was escaped, so copying the query into mysql worked, making this far more difficult to track down than it should have been.

This works:

```
$posts = Post::select('posts.*', DB::raw('count(post_views.id) as views_count'))
->join('post_views', function($join) {
    $join->on('posts.id', '=', 'post_views.post_id')
        ->where('post_views.created_at', '>=', DB::raw('DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)'));
    })
->groupBy('posts.id')
->orderBy('views_count', 'DESC')
```

With the important bit being: **DB::raw('DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)')**